# Bootstrap Carousel Caption Animation

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to slideToggle the caption within my carousel on each slide change (including on init). Actually it works well except when hovering. I'd like to clear my timeout but it doesn't affect..

http://jsfiddle.net/M63jw/

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function () {

    var carouselContainer = $('.carousel');
    var slideInterval = 3000;
    var carouselTimeout;

    carouselContainer
      .on('slid', function(){
        var caption = $(this).find('.active').find('.carousel-caption');

        caption.slideToggle();

        var carouselTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
          carouselTimeout = false;
          caption.slideToggle();
        }, slideInterval);

      })
      .on('slide', function(){
        if(carouselTimeout){
          clearTimeout(carouselTimeout);
          carouselTimeout = false;
        }
      });

    carouselContainer.carousel({
        interval: slideInterval,
        cycle: true,
        pause: "hover"
      }).trigger('slid');

    carouselContainer.hover(function(){
      clearTimeout(carouselTimeout);
      carouselTimeout = false;
    });

});
</script>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: could you post a jsfiddle showing the issue?

Comment: I updated my post with the jsfiddle

Comment: Its not entirely clear what behavior you want that is not there now.

Comment: When I hover the image the slider stops but the caption disappears after the slideIntervall time. I tried to prevent this by adding `carouselContainer.hover(function(){
      clearTimeout(carouselTimeout);
      carouselTimeout = false;
    });` but this doesn't change anything... So I actually just need to clear my timeout but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you over-complicated things a little bit with the timeout, you can simply use the events of `slid` ans `slide` to toggle your caption like this:

```
var carouselContainer = $('.carousel');
var slideInterval = 3000;

function toggleCaption(){
    var caption = carouselContainer.find('.active').find('.carousel-caption');
    caption.slideToggle();
}

carouselContainer.carousel({
    interval: slideInterval,
    cycle: true,
    pause: "hover"
}).on('slid slide', toggleCaption).trigger('slid');
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M63jw/4/)**