# Bootstrap carousel-caption animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to customize the carousel of `Boostrap3`.

Basically what I'm trying to do is:

- Making the `caption` appear a while after the image was loaded (to give
  the user the experience to see the pic a few secs, then the `caption`
  comes in)
- The `caption` should come from right to left.
- The `caption` needs to fill the entire pic.

What have I tried?

The carrousel-caption shows up from bottom to top and it works only on the first slide.

**Css markup**

```
.carousel-caption {
    display: none;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    background: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.5);
}
```

Followin a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17890775/bootstrap-carousel-caption-animation#17892387), I'm using this .js

**Js markup**

```
var carouselContainer = $('.carousel');
var slideInterval = 3000;

function toggleCaption(){
    var caption = carouselContainer.find('.active').find('.carousel-caption');
    caption.slideToggle();
}

carouselContainer.carousel({
    interval: slideInterval,
    cycle: true,
    pause: "hover"
}).on('slid slide', toggleCaption).trigger('slid');
```

Here's a live **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3abQk/1/)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To slide right to left you can add `jQuery UI` and use it in [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) for additional features, to wait a bit before start the animation you can use [`delay`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/).

The correct event to hook in bootstrap3 is `slid.bs.carousel`, see http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

Code:

```
var carouselContainer = $('.carousel');
var slideInterval = 3000;

function toggleCaption() {
    $('.carousel-caption').hide();
    var caption = carouselContainer.find('.active').find('.carousel-caption');
    caption.delay(500).toggle("slide", {direction:'right'});
}

carouselContainer.carousel({
    interval: slideInterval,
    cycle: true,
    pause: "hover"
}).on('slid.bs.carousel', function() {
    toggleCaption();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/Y6WH7/

### UPDATE

To fix the caption height add this `height: 100% !important;` to its css rule.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/Y6WH7/1/

Comment: You're right ´slid slide´ does the trick, I think that I should´ve read the documentation better before. Idk adding ´jQueryUI´ to the solution... Even tho, it has a little bug on the bottom, can you see it?. +1 btw and thx for the help!

Comment: Tottaly forgot to check '!important'. Thanks a lot, you solve my 2 days headache!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple snippet to fade the active caption, other animations such as sliding can be achieved using css transitions or other methods or js animation libs.

```
$('.carousel').carousel({
  interval: 800000,
  pause: 'true',
  cycle: true
}).on('slide.bs.carousel', (e) => {
  $(e.relatedTarget).find('.carousel-caption').fadeOut(500)
}).on('slid.bs.carousel', (e) => {
  $(e.relatedTarget).find('.carousel-caption').fadeIn(500)
})
```