# slide in bootstrap carousel caption

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hi with reference to this answer
[Bootstrap carousel-caption animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21206244/bootstrap-carousel-caption-animation/27498052#27498052)
i want to do the same with animate.css.i want to add class fadeInRightBig when the carousel slides.
how do i do this using the same answer given in the link

```
var carouselContainer = $('.carousel');
var slideInterval = 5000;

function toggleCaption() {
    // $('.carousel-caption').hide();
    var caption = carouselContainer.find('.active').find('.carousel-caption');
    caption.delay(500).toggleClass('animated fadeInRightBig');
}


carouselContainer.carousel({
    interval: slideInterval,
    cycle: true,
    pause: "hover"
}).on('slid.bs.carousel', function() {
    toggleCaption();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$('.carousel-caption').hide();  
$('.active .carousel-caption').delay(1500).addClass('rotateInDownLeft').show();
$('.carousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function() {
   $('.carousel-caption').hide();
   $('.carousel-caption').removeClass('rotateInDownLeft');
   $('.active .carousel-caption').offsetWidth = $('.active .carousel-caption').offsetWidth;
   $('.active .carousel-caption').delay(1500).addClass('rotateInDownLeft').show();
});
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/36BixvpmOu

**css / less**

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotateInDownLeft {
      0% {
        -webkit-transform-origin: left bottom;
                transform-origin: left bottom;
        -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -45deg);
                transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -45deg);
        opacity: 0;
      }

      100% {
        -webkit-transform-origin: left bottom;
                transform-origin: left bottom;
        -webkit-transform: none;
                transform: none;
        opacity: 1;
      }
    }

    @keyframes rotateInDownLeft {
      0% {
        -webkit-transform-origin: left bottom;
                transform-origin: left bottom;
        -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -45deg);
                transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -45deg);
        opacity: 0;
      }

      100% {
        -webkit-transform-origin: left bottom;
                transform-origin: left bottom;
        -webkit-transform: none;
                transform: none;
        opacity: 1;
      }
    }

    .rotateInDownLeft {
      -webkit-animation-name: rotateInDownLeft;
              animation-name: rotateInDownLeft;
      -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;  
              animation-duration: 0.6s;       
    }
```

see also: http://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/